# Continuously real-time fetching currently playing song on Spotify

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, api-design, vk

I wrote the script that puts Spotify user's currently playing song to the status on vk.com. It's like a one-time thing now. When you run the script - it sets the correct status. But to update it, you obviously will need to run the script again.

I wonder if there is a possibility to make it work dynamically? Update the status, when the new song starts. I can think only of a setting a schedule to run the script or sending requests to check if the song has changed. But I imagine it will work only if a user's PC is always on and hence the script is ready to run.

The other problem is that the spotify token lasts one hour, but I read that [the refresh token is practically valid forever, or until it has been manually revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372835/how-can-i-increase-the-expiry-time-of-spotify-token). Vk token has an official option to make token valid forever.

```
import config
import webbrowser
import requests
import furl
import secrets
import string
import time
import os
import simplejson as json


URL_CODE_BASE_VK = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize'
URL_CODE_BASE_SP = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
URL_TOKEN_VK = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token'
URL_TOKEN_SP = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
URL_TRACK = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing'
URL_STATUS = 'https://api.vk.com/method/status.set'
EXP_IN_TOKEN_SP = 3400
EXP_IN_TOKEN_VK = 86400
FILE_TOKEN_VK = 'vk_token.json'
FILE_TOKEN_SP = 'sp_token.json'


def get_auth_code_vk():
    url_code_params = {
                        'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID_VK,
                        'response_type': 'code',
                        'redirect_uri': 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html',
                        'v': 5.92,
                        'scope': 'status',
                        'state': gen_state(),
                        'display': 'page'
    }

    code = url_open(URL_CODE_BASE_VK, url_code_params)
    return parse_code(code)


def get_auth_code_sp():
    url_code_params = {
                        'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID_SP,
                        'response_type': 'code',
                        'redirect_uri': 'https://www.spotify.com/',
                        'scope': 'user-read-currently-playing',
                        'state': gen_state()
    }

    code = url_open(URL_CODE_BASE_SP, url_code_params)
    return parse_code(code)


def gen_state():
    symbols = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(symbols) for _ in range(12))


def url_open(url_base, url_params):
    url_code_full = furl.furl(url_base).add(url_params).url
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url_code_full)
    input_url = input('Enter the whole URL, that you have been redirected on: ')

    return input_url


def parse_code(url):
    return (url.split("code=")[1]).split("&state=")[0]


def get_token_vk():
    data = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': get_auth_code_vk(),
            'redirect_uri': 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html',
            'client_id': 6782333,
            'client_secret': config.CLIENT_SECRET_VK
    }

    response = requests.post(url=URL_TOKEN_VK, data=data).json()
    write_file(FILE_TOKEN_VK, response)


def get_token_sp():
    data = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': get_auth_code_sp(),
            'redirect_uri': 'https://www.spotify.com/',
            'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID_SP,
            'client_secret': config.CLIENT_SECRET_SP
    }

    response = requests.post(url=URL_TOKEN_SP, data=data).json()
    write_file(FILE_TOKEN_SP, response)


def write_file(tkn_file, response):
    dict = {}
    dict['token'] = response["access_token"]
    dict['time'] = time.time()

    with open(tkn_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(dict))


def load_file(tkn_file):
    with open(tkn_file) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data


def set_status():
    params = {
              'v': 5.92,
              'access_token': load_file(FILE_TOKEN_VK)['token'],
              'text': current_track()
    }

    set_status = requests.get(url=URL_STATUS, params=params)


def track_data():
    tkn_file =  load_file(FILE_TOKEN_SP)['token']
    headers = {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': f'Bearer {tkn_file}'
    }

    return requests.get(url=URL_TRACK, headers=headers)


def current_track():
    data = track_data().json()
    artist = data['item']['artists'][0]['name']
    track = data['item']['name']

    return(f'{artist} - {track}')


def check_playback():
    try:
        set_status()
        print(current_track())
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Not playing')


def token_missing(file):
    return not os.path.isfile(file)


def token_expired(file, exp_in):
    return time.time() - load_file(file)['time'] > exp_in


def token_not_valid(file, exp_in):
    return token_missing(file) or token_expired(file, exp_in)


def run_script():
    if token_not_valid(FILE_TOKEN_VK, EXP_IN_TOKEN_VK):
        get_token_vk()

    if token_not_valid(FILE_TOKEN_SP, EXP_IN_TOKEN_SP):
        get_token_sp()

    check_playback()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_script()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `cron` job to make a process run at set intervals. Also if you build this into a `flask` app then you can use a `scheduler` to run the job at set intervals. Probably `cron` is the quickest way though.
To edit cronjobs:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then add something like:

```
* * * * * python /tmp/spotify_update.py
```

To run the job every second. The asterisks represent minutes, hours, days, months, and weekdays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not using Linux or OS now. So cron is not for me, but there are some similar things available in Windows, as I hear. Anyway, this is not that I wanted. Since it needs a PC to be ON for the whole time. A web app is a way for me, but I'd prefer Django, probably there are some schedules for Django. It will be faster in Django or Flask? I mean to build this into a web app. If you are familiar with both of these. I didn't really touch the Flask yet.